# Restoring MySQL backup: how to specify max packet size in command line

Tags: macos, mysql

I am trying to restore a MySQL database from a dump file in my Mac OS X machine, but facing a `MySQL server has gone away` error.

I guess I have to configuring max_allowed_packet in the `my.cnf` file. But, there seem to be no `/ect/my.cnf` file installed.

How can I specify a max packet size in the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your configuration file in these locations - [Using Option Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html). Then add `max_allowed_packet` variable to the [mysqld] section, e.g. -

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1M
```

And restart server.

Comment: I cannot create file /ect/my.cnf, I face error "no such file or directory" in the terminal

Comment: There has to be '/ect' directory. Find it, and modify or create this file.

Comment: Default `my.cnf` locations are `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.